# How can I loop on string tokens in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'd like to tokenize a string representing a date format like DD/MM/YYYY in many elements such as DD, /, MM, /, YYYY and loop on them in order to transform

```
<tag date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" />
```

to

```
<container>
  <number:day number:style="long" />
  <number:text>/</number:text>
  <number:month number:style="long" />
  <number:text>/</number:text>
  <number:year number:style="long" />
</container>
```

Consequently, the tag

```
<tag date-format="MM-DD-YYYY" />
```

should be converted to

```
<container>
  <number:month number:style="long" />
  <number:text>-</number:text>
  <number:day number:style="long" />
  <number:text>-</number:text>
  <number:year number:style="long" />
</container>
```

I haven't the slightest idea how to do it in XSLT 1.0 whith no support of tokenizers nor regular expressions.

Please, take into account **I'm bound to XSLT 1.0 and cannot upgrade**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your starting point:

```
<xsl:template match="tag[@date-format]">
    <container>
        <xsl:call-template name="analyze-date-format">
            <xsl:with-param name="date-format" select="@date-format" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </container>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="analyze-date-format">
    <xsl:param name="date-format"/>
    <xsl:variable name="separators" select="translate($date-format, 'YMD', '')" />
    <xsl:variable name="separator" select="substring($separators, 1, 1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="token">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$separator">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($date-format, $separator)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$date-format" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$token = 'YYYY'">
            <number:year number:style="long" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$token = 'MM'">
            <number:month number:style="long" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$token = 'DD'">
            <number:day number:style="long" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose> 
    <xsl:if test="$separators">
        <number:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />
        </number:text>
         <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="analyze-date-format">
            <xsl:with-param name="date-format" select="substring-after($date-format, $separator)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming all tokens are in upper-case (and possibly some other presumptions too). You'll probably want to add more tests for additional token types.

Note that the `number:` prefix must be bound to a namespace!

Comment: That was a really brilliant solution, it worked like a charm!